# RESTful API not showing up with simple AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, api, rest

Alright, I'll try and explain this as simply as possible. I have setup a Node and express and mySQL server running a RESTful API with the common get, post, put, delete working fine as I can test them with them in Postman and just looking it up in Chrome. This is all run locally on my machines for now. I have a Ubuntu box running the REST api. When I just query in chrome I get an expected output of the fields I am working with.

(Example request "http://192.168.239.130:1337/api/plates/") Gives me this.

```
{
"Plates": [
    {
        "lot_number": "P234",
        "plate_number": "NGE-781",
        "date_and_time": "2016-07-08T21:14:31.000Z"
    },
    {
        "lot_number": "P234",
        "plate_number": "FEB-423",
        "date_and_time": "2016-07-08T21:26:08.000Z"
    },
    {
        "lot_number": "P234",
        "plate_number": "SEB-623",
        "date_and_time": "2016-07-08T21:26:20.000Z"
    },
    {
        "lot_number": "P234",
        "plate_number": "ZEB-683",
        "date_and_time": "2016-07-08T21:30:59.000Z"
    },
    {
        "lot_number": "P234",
        "plate_number": "FEW-083",
        "date_and_time": "2016-07-08T21:31:57.000Z"
    },
    {
        "lot_number": "L323",
        "plate_number": "JEQ-324",
        "date_and_time": "2016-07-11T18:59:03.000Z"
    }
   ]
 }
```

These are just some sample mySQL data that is printed to screen. Which is working as I had hoped. My problem is when I try to make a simple html page with angular script to try and print it it doesn't want to. All I get is a blank page. I have tried running my code with other api's online. I have no problem printing those out with the identical code which I will post below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="platesCtrl">

{{plates}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('platesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://192.168.239.130:1337/api/plates")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.plates = response.data;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Like I said running this with any other API online works.... Mine doesn't It it something that has to do with it be local? Even though like I stated I can run the above address to the ....api/plates API in a browser no problem and get the JSON to spit out.

Any knowledge would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: What does your network tab in Chrome say? It is probably a cross domain issue.

Comment: Do you have an error message if you use the error callback of the promise ?

```app.controller('platesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http
       .get("http://192.168.239.130:1337/api/plates")
       .then(
           function (response) {
               $scope.plates = response.data;
           },
           function (error) {
               console.log('Response error: ', error);
           },
       );
});```

Comment: So I totally missed what the console said. 'Access-control-Allow-Origin' missing.

Comment: I added to my Node and Express server the Access-control-Allow-Origin header to every Res on each API call... That was able to fix it for now. Is there more of a universal way to do this to every API so I don't have to add to every single one?

Comment: check out the CORS package on npm: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll answer this myself. Thought from the comments given from a few other users. I checked the console and was given an error that states that I have a cross domain issue and that 'Access-control-Allow-Origin' missing. I was able to fix be going into my API calling functions and add

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

to every API call. For now this works though I am sure there is a more elegant way to implement the same thing.

Thanks for the help.